# Mediawiki, enlarge table in infobox

Tags: mediawiki

I have an infobox in a template, where I'd like to add a table.

I added it, but could not obtain a good result.

An example of infobox is:

[image]

But I want the table in "composition" section to be as large as the rest of infobox.

Here the source code (I cut for the interesting parts):

```
{| style="float:right;border:1px solid gold"
! colspan="2" style="background:gold;width:200px;font-size:10pt" | {{#external_value:common_name}}
|-
| colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size:10pt" | [http://m.muninn.land/coins/{{#external_value:obverse_image}}]<br />
|-
| colspan="2" style="background:gold;text-align:center;font-size:9pt" | Description
|-
| style="font-size:9pt" | Currency: || style="font-size:9pt" | {{#external_value:currency_name}}
|-
```

Cut 8<

```
| style="font-size:9pt" | Form factor: || style="font-size:9pt" | {{#external_value:form_factor}}
|-
| colspan="2" style="background:gold;text-align:center;font-size:9pt" | Composition
|-
| colspan="2" style="font-size:9pt;text-align:left" | {{coin composition|id={{{id|2}}}}}
|}
```

Where the table in template "coin composition" is:

```
{| class="wikitable"
! Material:
! Percentage: {{#for_external_table:<nowiki/>
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{composition}}}
{{!}} {{{percentage}}}
}}
|}
```

I tried to adjust column width:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Column_width

but not with good results...

How can I enlarge the table in the infobox?

For example, a page of the site, in beta, is online at http://en.muninn.land/index.php/1000_lire_Capital_Rome_1970
for full source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `style="width: 100%"` to the table.

```
{| class="wikitable" style="width: 100%"
! Material:
! Percentage: {{#for_external_table:<nowiki/>
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{composition}}}
{{!}} {{{percentage}}}
}}
|}
```

But a better solution would be to integrate composition into the main infobox (the template `Coin details`).

Rewrite the `Coin composition` template thus:

```
|-
| style="font-size:9pt" | Material: || style="font-size:9pt" | Percentage:
{{#get_db_data:
 db=munin
 |from=geo.v_coin_composition
 |where=comp_coin_id={{{id|1}}}
|data=comp_coin_id=comp_coin_id,composition=composition,percentage=percentage
}}
{{#for_external_table:<nowiki/>
{{!}}-
{{!}} style="font-size:9pt" {{!}} {{{composition}}}
{{!}} style="font-size:9pt" {{!}} {{{percentage}}}
}}
|}
```

Invoke it from a new line and remove the preceding

```
|-
| colspan="2" style="font-size:9pt;text-align:left" |
```

Or simply replace its invocation with its new source code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used first solution. I understand second one, but first seems to be more reusable.